# Unable to build assembly: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement with karaf-bundle-plugin

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I've created an example bundle project with maven-bundle-plugin, and the following MANIFEST.MF was created:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1486554665411
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Bundle-Description: Helper classes
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: core.util
Bundle-SymbolicName: core.util
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.example.core.util;version="1.0.0",com.example.core.util.ex
 tension;version="1.0.0"
Originally-Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-3.2.0.201605172007
```

Now I've added that bundle as the dependency to the assembly build with maven-karaf-plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-karaf-dist</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>karaf-assembly</packaging>

    <dependencies>

(...)

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.example</groupId>
          <artifactId>core.util</artifactId>
          <version>${taxcloud.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>       
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <bootFeatures>
                        <feature>standard</feature>
                        <feature>webconsole</feature>
                    </bootFeatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

However, I'm unable to build because I get the following error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.7:assembly
>   (default-assembly) on project example-karaf-dist: Unable to build
>   assembly: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root]
>   osgi.identity; osgi.identity=core.util; type=osgi.bundle;
>   version="[1.0.0.SNAPSHOT,1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory
>   [caused by: Unable to resolve core.util/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT: missing
>   requirement [core.util/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.ee;
>   filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"] -> [Help 1]

I've failed to understand the error message, what can't be found here? I have core.util bundle in version 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT, so everything should work. What is the problem here? How can I include my bundle in karaf assembly?

Comment: Which java version do you use for the build?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider 1.8, and the manifest contains information it was built with that version.

Comment: Your pom above is malformed: <groupId>com.example/groupId>

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE thanks for finding out, but the original is non/malformed

Answer (score 0):

As I know the karaf-assembly target of karaf-maven plugin is to make distribution from the referenced feature descriptors. To do that make a feature descriptor first which contains your bundle definition and required feature definitions and after use that feature descriptor as depencency of the karaf-assembly pom. So I think the problem is you bundle is defined as normal dependency directly.